# Replace TLSClientConfig inside the transport of an http.Client?

Tags: go

Please consider this question.

`ourClient` is an `*http.Client` - once it is generated, how can `TLSClientConfig` (which is of type `tls.Config{}`) alone be changed of this http.Client?

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    transport := &http.Transport{
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        Dial: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   1 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
        }).Dial,
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{},
    }

    ourClient := &http.Client{
        Timeout:   5 * time.Second,
        Transport: transport,
    }

    fmt.Printf("http.Client Timeout %v\n", ourClient.Timeout)
    ourClient.Timeout = 3 * time.Second
    fmt.Printf("http.Client Timeout %v\n", ourClient.Timeout)

    // how do I replace the TLSClientConfig in ourClient
    // newTLSClientConfig := &tls.Config{}
    // ourClient.Transport.TLSClientConfig = newTLSClientConfig
    // ourClient.Transport.TLSClientConfig undefined (type http.RoundTripper has no field or method TLSClientConfig)

    fmt.Printf("http: %#v\n", ourClient)
}
```

(Also posted as https://go.dev/play/p/v1HJLZ-MhhH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.RoundTripper` is an *interface* - you need to convert it to the concrete implementation using a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions), e.g.:

```
    ...
    newTLSClientConfig := &tls.Config{}
    if tpt, ok := ourClient.Transport.(*http.Transport); ok {
        tpt.TLSClientConfig = newTLSClientConfig
    }
    ...
```

https://go.dev/play/p/2UinL3Uazid

It's probably better explained [here](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15), but FWIW - [http.Client.Transport](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client) is declared as a [RoundTripper](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#RoundTripper) *interface* and an *interface* can have many different implementations and none of them are guaranteed by the *interface* contract to have a `TLSClientConfig` field. So the Go compiler won't let you assign `newTLSClientConfig` field - because it legally can't.

A *type assertion* asserts that the concrete implementation of the interface conforms to the type and also assigns the implementation of the interface (`http.Transport` in this case) to the variable (`tpt` in this case). So `tpt` is now guaranteed to be an instance of `http.Transport` which means you can now assign `newTLSClientConfig` to the `TLSClientConfig` field.

If `ok` had been false it would have meant that the implementation of the `RoundTripper` interface was not an `http.Transport`.

Comment: Wow that is sheer genius - could you please take the time to explain the magic from those lines? (That would be immensely helpful, I can't quite comprehend whats going on here. TIA!)

Comment: Added an explanation, but TBH there are probably better ones out there - Google 'golang type assertion'